# aframe.io: how to add video controls (play, pause, volume, current time) to videosphere?

Tags: aframe

**What's the best way to add video controls to videosphere?**

`play, pause, volume, current time`

Answer (score 3):

Got answer from [framevr.slack.com](https://aframevr.slack.com/) response by [@ngokevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5965986/ngokevin)

There is video control component for A-Frame.

https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-video-controls